# Is there a way to know whether a C# method of a object is called or not?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to know whether a C# method of a object is called or not using reflection?

Comment: My guess is OP wants an AOP-like way of adding code to determine which code paths are exercised.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable answers.
Actually my scenario is quite simple. I'm working on a existing project which use the following way to change value in Database.

If the property of the class is null, do not change this value in Database, so that client can only initialize the class with need change properties. But sometimes some property maybe change to null, this scenario will not supported in the current logic.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out if your method is called is to use a code coverage tool. Visual studio Ultimate contains such tools to help determine code coverage. You first instrument your code, and then run your tests, or exercise your app normally, and then check your results.

Or you can just use a text editor to search for the method name in your source code. (That is by far the easiest).

Answer (score 0):

No. Reflection only know how a type is constructed and not how it's called by your application.

You can create an array of **StackFrame** inside a method to know how it was called.

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) can check if a method is called or not (it's a Visual Studio plugin)

Comment: I doubt Resharper can tell with 100% accuracy.

Comment: I did not claim that it would, did I? Although it does a very good job as long as all assemblies are in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to find out whether a specific method will ever be called in any scenario and for any input, then reflection can't do it for you.

You need tools to do the static program analysis, but these are not quite meant to be used at runtime.

If you could describe in more details what you're trying to accomplish, we might suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find any methods in your assembly that are never called by any other part of the assembly, [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) has a "dead code" rule that will find any such methods.

The dead code search does not include methods which can be called from the outside world, such as public methods though.